# Why would LDAP query work with asp.net but not with classic asp

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, ldap, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to setup LDAP connection code with another domain. My Windows server 2k3 is part of domain A. I'm trying to LDAP domain B. Now here's what I do:

```
test = "LDAP://CN=a,OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Domain"
Set connAD=getobject(test)
```

This gives error '80072020'

Same I do in asp.net:

```
DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=a,OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Domain");
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(user);
```

This works.

If I change the authentication mechanism from Integrated Windows to Basic then both work. I can't figure out what exactly is the issue.

Comment: your ASP example is incomplete.

Comment: What information are you looking for

Comment: what is `ads` and how is `test` used?

Comment: I'm so sorry, mistake in copy paste.Fixed it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

`GetObject` is not for querying LDAP. You will need a COM component to query LDAP.

Comment: It works when I query the domain in which the server resides. I'm not familiar with the concept, but I can tell you the codebase I inherited, it works there.It's not working for the new domain in classic asp.

Answer (score 0):

The way I once implemented was to use ADODB. Something like this :

```
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Properties("User ID") = "[DOMAIN]\[USERNAME]" 
connAD.Properties("Password") = "[PASSWORD]"
connAD.Properties("Encrypt Password") = true
connAD.Open

set test = "LDAP://CN=a,OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Domain"

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set rsADUserInfo = conn.Execute(test)
```

Comment: I'm trying to obtain user object with using user id and password.